# PHP script didn't show correct data on server shell

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, file-get-contents

I want to run this script:

```
<?php
    $file = file_get_contents('data.json');
    echo ($file);
    unset($file);
    exit(0);
 ?>
```

If I access this over ajax in JS there are no problems, but if I run this script on my servers shell with `php script.php` or `php -f script.php` there is allways an older version of this JSON string shown. Over ajax I receive allways the newest data from this script.

Finally i need this script to be included in another php script which runs a loop for detecting changes. This also didn't receive the newest data.

Comment: is the php file and the JS in the same directory? Seems to me this is likely a pathing issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$file = file_get_contents( __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'data.json');
echo ($file);
unset($file);
exit(0);
?>
```

data.json should be in the same directory as your php file.